# how to do a vertex merge after a split

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, edges, instances

why is one of these vertices joined correctly and the other is not?
they are both in group B Is there another way I could do the same thing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vertex-groups are not inherently Boolean.. a weight has to be absolutely 0 or unassigned to be `False` .. I guess there's room for error here? Could you share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ...

Comment: Thanks! .. (edited in for you).

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify, looking only at the relevant area, outputting well before the final output of the GN, and applying the modifier so we can see what it did:

[image]

Tab into edit.  First, check out the marked vertex, and notice that it was merged properly, just like you told it to.  But now, look at the vertices that adjoin the B-marked vertex and move them.  We see that B doesn't connect two edges, but rather four:

[image]

Blender cannot support branching curves, so it cannot turn this into a single continuous curve (or spline, I always forget which terminology they use for which.)  It needs to divide it into at least two sections, and it's going to do so arbitrarily.  When it does so, it chooses to divide them like this:

[image]

Of course, this is with the vertices of those segments moved, so that we can see them.  In your file, those vertices are at the exact same location, so it just looks like two unconnected segments (even though each segment actually contains doubled geometry.)

Comment: Within geometry nodes, a curve and a spline are synonymous and they are used interchangeably. There is no node that would somehow discriminate objects based on their type (mesh / curve / light etc.), and so both a spline and a curve simply mean, what is a spline outside of geonodes (in Blender; because outside of Blender those terms are also used interchangeably…)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I thought one of them referred to particular "islands" in a potentially disconnected set?  Like "curve index" parameter in "sample curve", which I guess suggests that if curves had indices, that a spline is the overall set.  Although I guess "is spline cyclic" seems opposite, since this isn't a parameter of the entire set.  If they are used interchangeably, that's kind of irritating for search purposes, I always thought there was a reason.

Comment: one could think that maybe a curve is the entire string from the beginning to the end, an "island" as you put it, whereas a spline is a segment, especially making sense in case of beziers… But no, both terms "curve" and "spline" refer to those "islands".